# How to make DEBUG CONSOLE as default tab in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to learn Python. How can I make DEBUG CONSOLE as default tab in Visual Studio Code? Whenever I debug, this tool loads terminal which has lot of text which is confusing. I click on DEBUG CONSOLE tab to see my output. Wondering if there is any way to get rid of that terminal tab (just the tab, I understand we need terminal for code to work). I tried right clicking on TERMINAL tab and hiding it, but it hides only temporarily. Help appreciated.

Also, what does OUTPUT tab do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press the hotkey to get the debug console:

```
Windows: Ctrl + Shift + D 
macOS: shift + command + Y
```

Edit: In your project repo, find `.vscode/launch.json` file (create one if none exists) and add the following:

```
{
    "version": "3.5",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then relaunch VSCode for the change to take effect.

Comment: Hi Gnoliz,
I'd like to avoid doing any click or keyboard hit.

Comment: @AbhijithKolanakuduru I've updated my answer and tested on my computer.

Comment: Hi Gnoliz, Superb. It works. Any idea what OUTPUT tab does?

Comment: @AbhijithKolanakuduru Hi. The output tab is for the code runner extension. Install code runner and press Ctrl + Alt+ N to run your code. Hope that helps. By the way, could you accept my answer if it works for you? Thanks

Comment: @AbhijithKolanakuduru Hello?

Comment: `"console": "none"` is no longer an accepted input these days but you can output it to the terminal by setting it to `"console": "integratedTerminal"` instead.

Comment: @AbhijithKolanakuduru The Output tab shows debug output for each of VSCode's own internals as well as output from extensions.